# IE8 changing GET request to POST: Angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

I am making call to a REST service from my AngularJS app using $http. The issue is whenever I make a GET request from IE8, it gets converted to POST request. Calls with other http methods (POST,PUT) work fine. This happens only with IE8.
Here is my code
```

```
var request = {method: method, url: url, data: payload};
var promise =  $http(request) .then(function (response) {
                    return response;
                });
```

```
Can someone please help. I have tried sending different types off data payload : null,undefined,empty object, some object. But nothing worked.

Comment: AngularJS on IE8.. Yikes, a clash of eras.

Comment: Probably best to do it with jQuery and use $q to manage the promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. We need to send empty string as payload. Or, use $http.get